# querying current and previous relationships using has_many through: in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

I have a project management app that has 3 models…Project, Users, and Participation.  I would like to be able to show a list of all the Users who have collaborated with a given User on any of the Projects the Given User was a Participant in. This includes past Projects.

For Instance UserA & UserB were in ProjectBlue
UserA & UserC were in ProjectYellow
UserA & UserC  & UserD were in ProjectRed

If I am in UserA’s dashboard I want to be able to see a list that says:

"You’ve worked with:
UserC(only listed once)
UserD
UserB”

Do I need to create a whole :relationships Table with a :user_id, :project_id,  record for EVERY shared connection? This doesn’t seem efficient.

**Models**

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # (this is the organizer)
  has_many :users, through: :participants
  has_many :participants

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :projects
  has_many :project, through :participant
  has_many :participants

Class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way. Database space is free and the database is bored anyway. It'll appreciate some data to work with. ;-)

Have a look at http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/ar-many_to_many.html for some examples.

But I'm not sure about your models. They do seem to be a bit strange. You probably want:

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # (this is the organizer)
  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, through: :participants

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :participants
  has_many :projects, through: :participants

Class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: thank you. Should I remove the :user_id (as organizer) index from Projects and just store the organizer relationship in Participants?

Comment: Has one project always one owner or can a project have many owners?

Comment: a project has one CREATOR, but several can update it. I just want a record of who made it.  Like, an assistant might physically create the Project, but a manager would "own" it.

Comment: For recording all changes you want to have a look at https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail